# Dropdown list population

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql

Two dropdown lists - Select first value, then mysql_query returns the answer, and whit this data populate second dropdown list. 
Problem is - the second list doesn't seem to be populated. The code works fine - I see output in firebug.

```
<form method="post" action="showResult.php" >
<input type=hidden name="style" value="segment">
Choose wisely
<select name="pillow" id="pillow">
    <option value="0">choose</option>
    <option value="1">Red</option>
    <option value="2">Blue</option>
</select>
Now, what do you want to start with?
<select id="ANSWER" name="ANSWER" size="1">
    <option value="0">-</option> // this doesn't want to populate
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#pillow").change(function(){
        $("#ANSWER").load(".test.php", { 
            id: $("#pillow option:selected").val() 
        });
    });
</script>
</form>
```

The `test.php`:

```
<?php
    include 'init.php';//here we do all stuff with connections and etc.
    $name = $_REQUEST["id"];
    //prevent simple injection
    if(strstr($name,'.') || strstr($name, "\0")) die ("Be sure - it won't work =)");
    mysql_query('SET NAMES "utf8"'); // should it be here? 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT action FROM table WHERE pillow='$name'") or die('MySQL error!'. mysql_error()); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    //I see this log in firebug, but not in the dropdown list
    printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>',$row['action'],$row['action']); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Any error do you getting?

Comment: have you tried adding the `printf('<select>');` befor the loop and `printf('</select>');` after?

Comment: @KiranRS, none. In Firebug there was the desirable output. But not in the list.

Comment: @user3052629, hello. No, but what about <select id="ANSWER" name="ANSWER" size="1">
    <option value="0">-</option>
</select>
There is already an empty list, which had to be populated

Comment: what `print_r('$row['action']')` output?

Comment: @user3052629, Yes, I just tried - still nothing

Comment: try ".test.php" to "test.php"

Comment: @KiranRS, . means current dir, right? So it finds the php file, runs the script, script in log returns all that printf should return, but the dropdown doesn't populate

Comment: No, ./ means current. You really shouldn't use that in a URL (in fact I've never tried that, so I don't even know if you can). Works in the script itself though.

Comment: @Zarazthuztra, hello. Got it. Now removed the dot - still nothing.

Comment: @BraveS, good, that's one potential issue resolved, now to investigate further!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put quotes around your id param that you are sending to the server. In your current implementation you're sending a variable value as the key and not the key "id".

Change this:

```
id: $("#pillow option:selected").val()
```

to this:

```
"id": $("#pillow option:selected").val()
```

I'll take the rest of this answer to mention the security holes in your script:

1) The mysql_ function set is deprecated, please consider switching to [mysqli](http://www.php.net/mysqli) as soon as possible

2) At least escape values being passed into a query as a value, currently you are allowing any value to be placed into your query, leaving you open to sql injection attacks. If you are using the deprecated mysql_ function set, use mysql_real_escape_string() to sanitize the variable. If you are using mysqli, use prepared statements with bindings.

Comment: he might want to check PDO, i find PDO more friendly to me.

Comment: I like PDO a lot as well, I'm just thinking of it from an "easy to migrate " perspective. First use the procedural approach of mysqli (which is closer to the mysql approach), then migrate from that to the OO approach of mysqli, then say screw this I'm grabbing an ORM lib/framework

Comment: lol, well, i like pdo because i saw it in a tutorial i watched, and he just made it so simply, so i dont know how to use mysqli.

Comment: yea well, i'm very newbie to the whole thing, i know how to use it, i just dont know alot, so i can make a website from nada, but it will take me time and research, but i'm learning on the go, dont my own web and watching lots of tuts

Comment: I think that's wonderful! Some folks are gonna tell you to not re-create the wheel, but honestly building your own wheel is the best way to understand how it works at its most basic level. Good luck!

Comment: thanks, well people always are talking, the question is how you listen to them.

Comment: Exactly :) I think that's sound advice!